# Windows Task Scheduler - Outlook send/receive Mail

Tags: email, outlook, task, scheduled-tasks, event-viewer

**Backgroundinfo:**

- I am currently working on a project which runs on UiPath and includes Outlook.
  I need the Windows Task Scheduler to schedule a Task once an E-Mail is coming in.

**The Problem:**

- I understand in order to schedule a Task on an event an **Event ID** is needed - as far as I know there is no EventID for receiving E-Mails, but I heard that there is one for sending E-Mails.

**The Workaround:**

- If an E-Mail is received, with Outlook-Rules I send an automatic response and upon sending there should be the "Sending E-Mail"-Event and with that I can Schedule a Task.

That's it for the theory but I can't find the EventID I need, does it even exist? Am I looking in the wring places?

I tried sending an E-Mail whilst checking with the "Event-Viewer" if any Event fires, but nothing happens. 
The only Outlook ID's I can find are:

1. ID 32: The store C:\(...) has detected a catalog checkpoint.
2. ID 45: Outlook loaded the following add-in(s): (...)
3. ID 63: The Exchange web service request GetAppManifests succeeded.

Answer (score 3):

You will not meet such information in the Windows event viewer. Instead, I'd suggest developing a COM add-in for Outlook where you can handle the [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/application-newmailex-event-outlook) event of the Application class which is fired when a new item is received in the Inbox. See [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook) for more information.

The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/namespace-getitemfromid-method-outlook) method and process the item. Use this method with caution to minimize the impact on Outlook performance. However, depending on the setup on the client computer, after a new message arrives in the Inbox, processes like spam filtering and client rules that move the new message from the Inbox to another folder can occur asynchronously.

You can treat a VSTO add-in as a regular .Net application where you can do whatever you need.

Comment: I'll look into this! Thank you.